# Laravel eloquent with categories

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question about eloquent in laravel.

DB tables

> categories: id root_id name
>
> products id  name etc..
>
> product_categories id product_id category_id

So it might be CategoryA which has a child CategoryB and CategoryB by itself has a child CategoryC.

When I click in CategoryA I want to find all products that are part of CategoryA, CategoryB, CategoryC

```
Category Model

   public function cats()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }


    public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('cats');
    }
```

Product Model

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

Controller

//firsty I get all id of all categories, subcategories of all levels.

```
        $categories = Category::where('category_id',$category_id)->with('childrenCategories')->get();
        $all_cat_array=array();$all_prod=array();

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
        array_push($all_cat_array, $childCategory->id);
    }
    array_push($all_cat_array,$category->id);

}
```

//then i get all id of products

```
foreach ($all_cat_array as $cat)
{
    if(CategoryProduct::where('category_id',$cat)->exists()) {
        $prod=CategoryProduct::where('category_id',$cat)->pluck('product_id');
        array_push($all_prod,$prod );
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use of all these foreach, since I want to optimise the code.
What can I do to make it simplier ???

Comment: CategoryA has a relation to CategoryB. Is it **one to many** relationship ?

Comment: Yeah . It is like: CategoryA whth id 1  has no root_id, on the other hand the root_id of CateogryB is 1

Answer (score 0):

For more information please read [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships)

**DATABASE**

**Category A database**

```
Schema::create('category_as', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
  ...
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Category B database**

```
Schema::create('category_bs', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_a_id');
  ...
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('category_a_id')->references('id')->on('category_as')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**MODEL**

**Products model**

```
public function categories_a() {
  return $this->hasmany(Category_a::class);
}
```

**Category A model**

```
public function categories_b() {
  return $this->hasmany(Category_b::class);
}

public function product() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**Category B model**

```
public function category_a() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Category_a::class);
}

public function clients() {
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Client::class, Code::class);
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index() {
  $products = Product::all();
  $query = $products->categories_a->categories_b;
  dd($query);
}
```

**EDITED**

**DATABASE**

**Category A database**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
  ...
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**MODEL**

**Products model**

```
public function categories() {
  return $this->hasmany(Category::class);
}
```

**Category model**

```
public function product() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index() {
  $products = Product::all();
  $query = $products->categories;
  dd($query);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have only one table called categories. Which means I have only one model. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Hey is there a solution?

Comment: please be specific on your question tell me what you want

Comment: Thank you again but you still haven't understood me :/  It is a many to many relationship. I have also a table category_product.  I wanna show all products of a category ( which has subcategories and also subcategories have subcategories by itself and so on ( a never ending cycle))

Comment: Heyy I found I way but I need your help to optimize the codee... Can you please help me? Thanks in advance?

Comment: if your problem was that can you please illustrate in image the relationship you want with line (like a connect the dots question) e.g `product - category` & `category - sub category a`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use nested set structure in Category model.

It is well implemented in this package https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset.

You could get products of category and all it's descendants (with unlimited nesting) with 2 queries.

**If Category belongsToMany Product:**

```
$categoryIds = Category::descendantsAndSelf($categoryId)->pluck('id');

$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categoryIds) {
    $query->whereIn('categories.id', $categoryIds);
});
```

**If Category hasMany Product**

```
$categoryIds = Category::descendantsAndSelf($categoryId)->pluck('id');

$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds);
```